# How to add custom text when an order is created at Shopify

Tags: shopify

When a customer purchases a product from Shopify, at the checkout point, I want to send a custom piece of text with a link where he can go, sign up, and start availing the very service for which he purchased the product.

The text would appear right there when a user would check out.

What I have tried so far:

I know very little about Shopify, so I have been going through its documentation, read a few articles here and there, and it seems like I have been unable to grasp the basic how-to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an order is completed at checkout, the customer is transferred to the Order Details page where you, the merchant get to say Thank You!

This page is customizable by you. Some simple examples of what merchants put on this page are things like a map, and when the order has a tracking number, stuff like showing where the package is. In other words, this is a good place to welcome the customer to their thing. You have access to some of the order details, allowing you to place a link there that might say "Hey! Amigo! We love you and thank you for order #1234. You can click here and take full advantage right now!"

The most basic stuff about this is in fact clearly explained and defined by Shopify in their documents. Look for info about the Order Status page. For example:

https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/orders/status-tracking/order-status-javascript-asset

Following the instructions, I pasted this simple snippet of code into the Additional Scripts and it worked perfect:

```
<script>
  var orderId = {{ order.id }};
  Shopify.Checkout.OrderStatus.addContentBox(
    '<h2>Everybody do the fizzbuzz</h2>',
    '<p>Order was order was was was ' + orderId + '</p>'
  )
</script>
```

Comment: This was indeed helpful. One more thing: I added some HTML there, and it's appearing like as it is. How to get it interpreted? You don't have to answer this exactly – you can guide me to somewhere as well where I can read & understand the stuff.

Comment: I mean: the HTML is appearing as it is. It's not being rendered on the page where I get to say thank you. Nor, the Liquid variables are working. Is there any catch with it?

Comment: I just edited my post... it is really simple. I do not have a clue why you are struggling with the concept! Sorry.